# Getting an error while adding nodes in a graph using networkx

Tags: python-3.x, graph

I want to create a graph where I have an input number of nodes known, below is what I tried.

import networkx as nx

def create_a_graph(user_input_for_nodes):
G = nx.Graph
for i in range(user_input):
G.add_node(i)
print(G)

create_a_graph(7)

Below is the error I received:-

TypeError: add_node() missing 1 required positional argument: 'node_for_adding'

Answer (score 0):

The method `add_node` requires an aditional argument called `node_for_adding`.

```
add_node(i, node_for_adding=?)
```

Try to look in the code base where this method is defined.
In VSCode, type `CTRL+SHIFT+F` then look for
`def add_node(`.

From there, you can see what type of argument is `node_for_adding`.

If there is any test using that signature, you can also see how it is used. For that, just look for other places in the code where `add_node` is used.